# How to stop Kubuntu from asking OpenPGP passphrase always on boot?

Tags: kubuntu

Whenever I boot into Kubuntu, it always tells me to enter the passphrase for my OpenPGP secret key. How can I disable this or not always have to enter it in every time?

[image: screenshot]

OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS,
KDE Plasma version: 5.24.7